# What are the possible shadowMapTypes?

Tags: three.js

What are the possible shadomMapTypes for renderer?

Currently i know 3:
THREE.

```
PCFShadowMap
PCFSoftShadowMap
PCFBasicShadowMap
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shadowMap types are:

```js
THREE.BasicShadowMap 
THREE.PCFShadowMap 
THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap
THREE.VSMShadowMap
```

See https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/constants/Renderer

three.js r159

Comment: The shadowing type constants are defined here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r56/src/Three.js#L107

Comment: The latest contains an additional shadowMap type VSM https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.shadowMap